# Changing Run Command in template for Netbeans project - Maintaining settings through new project creation

Tags: netbeans, ide, project

I'm running into some issues when configuring the properties of a new project template in netbeans.
I have my own script to build and run the project, so I have netbeans call the script in the "Run Command" area of the project properties. I just replaced

```
"${OUTPUT_PATH}"       # default command in the Run Command
```

with

```
runProject.sh          # location of my run script
```

However, I've created a template for new projects.

How do I get those settings to persist during the creation of a project?

**EDIT:**
I did some looking, and it looks like the Run Command settings are stored in `configurations.xml` inside the `nbproject/private/` folder.

Unfortunately, this folder doesn't seem to be copied over from the template when a new instance is created.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to force the template to copy that file over.

Comment: You should probably post a bug at the netbeans tracker and post the report here as an answer